CheckMK proxy-register flag not working
So I'm currently in the process of setting up a checkMK monitoring instance for testing. This spans several VLAN's and some of these are very restricted via firewall rules.
This means that for some instances the agent is unable to register inwards via port tcp8000, but checkmk server can pull it when registered.
Thus I am trying to do a proxy-register according to the documentation. Checkmk 
cmk-agent-ctl proxy-register --hostname serverhostname.local --server x.x.x.x --site sitex --user agent_registration > /tmp/serverhostname.json

Expected outcome:
This should render some output either in the file specified or if done without sending it to the file it should give some output in stdout. This can later be imported on a server that can reach checkmk server at x.x.x.x /tcp8000.
Actual outcome:
Checkmk agent treats command as regular "registration" and tries to reach the checkmk server at x.x.x.x /tcp8000 but returns error as x.x.x.x can not be reached.
I might have overlooked something here but I cannot figure out what.
Agent-version 2.3.0,
Server version 2.3.0p3

You need to run this command on a server, that actually has access to the Checkmk site on port 8000. The ideal candidate for that is the Checkmk server itself. This will generate the .json file, which you can transfer to the to-be-monitored system and import it there.

Thank you! The wording in the documentation being translated from german got me confused. Couldn't have helped being in a rush either.
It works now!
